# Daredevil Run not appearing

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

I picked up Super Mario Galaxy 2 again because I never completed it. Now I'm at Grandmaster Galaxy 1 already, and I got the first star and the comet thingy, but Squizzard's Daredevil Run doesn't show up.
Does anyone know why the Perfect Run is not there?

Comment: Have you gotten all the green stars?

Comment: While editing your question, it seems you are suggesting both the Perfect Run and the Daredevil Run are not showing up. Is this true, or is it either one?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/The_Perfect_Run):

> This mission can only be played after two conditions have been met: the player needs to have **collected the Comet Medal** from the previous mission and the player needs to have **9,999 Star Bits** stored with the Banktoad. Completing both conditions will cause the Prankster Comet to appear, allowing the player to play the mission.

Make sure you have 9,999 Star Bits as well, if you got the Comet Medal already.